# FQL query doesn't retrive all data it should (some results omitted)

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get all posts by users on a page with this query :

```
SELECT post_id, source_id, created_time, app_data, type, actor_id, target_id, attachment, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = MY_PAGE_ID AND actor_id != MY_PAGE_ID  LIMIT 50
```

The requests actually works, but some posts are omitted.

If anyone had also this issue, and know how to solve it, it could be very helpful. If you know also a better way (which works well) to get all posts by users on a page, it could help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am using below fql and it is working fine for me. Hope this helps.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+post_id,source_id,created_time+**"OTHER FILEDS REQUIRED"**+from+stream+where+post_id+in(select+post_id+from+stream+where+source_id=" **YOUR PAGE ID** ")&access_token="**ACCESS TOKEN**"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your fql works also but i had the same problem of posts omitted. If you have some time to check the results with this page ID : 120830871277097 and compare it to the recent posts by others on this page : http://www.facebook.com/Quechua you will see that some posts aren't retrieved.

Comment: I am not getting whether the posts are omitted from the end means only few posts are comming or in the middle of two posts.

Comment: In the middle of two posts, not in the end.